# Simplify the Indices

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Simplify

$$6^x \cdot 12^{2x+2} \div 27^x \cdot 32^{3x}$$

I did this: $$(2.3)^x \cdot (2 \cdot 3 \cdot 2)^{2x+2} \div (3 \cdot 3 \cdot 3)^x \cdot (2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2^3)^{3x}$$

Then: $$2^x \cdot 3^x \cdot 2^{2x+2} \cdot 3^{2x+2} \cdot 2^{2x+2}\div3^x \cdot 3^x \cdot 3^x \cdot 2^{3x} \cdot 2^{3x} \cdot 2^{9x}$$

$$=2^{5x+4} \cdot 3^{3x+2} \div 3^{3x} \cdot 2^{15x}$$

$$=2^{5x+4-15x} \cdot 3^{3x+2-3x}$$

$$=2^{-10x+4} \cdot 3^2$$

This is what I got, but the answer in my book says: $$2^{-20x+4} \cdot 3^2$$

Who's right? (I hope I provided all the information!)

Comment: Assuming you have copied the problem correctly, you are correct.

Comment: Yeah I copied it correctly! Thanks! @JohnHabert

Comment: where? I'll check if you tell me! :(

Comment: @Kiara The line starting Then. You have $3x^{2x+2}.2x^{2x+2}$ when it should be $3^{2x+2}.2^{2x+2}$. I ignored them since they disappeared later and so I assumed they were typos.

Comment: Ooops! sorry! that was a mistake! :'( @JohnHabert

Comment: yeah I got it. I deleted the comment! :P @JohnHabert lol...

Answer (score 2):

$(6^x\times 12^{2x+2})\div (27^x\times 32^{3x})$

$=(2^x\times 3^x \times 2^{2(2x+2)} \times 3^{2x+2})\div (3^{3x}\times 2^{5(3x)})$

$=2^{x+4x+4-15x}\times 3^{x+2x+2-3x}$

$=2^{-10x+4}\times 3^2$